# How to make APFS snapshot tidemark smaller?

Tags: macos, partitioning, disk-utility

I want to install Windows on another partition, so I want to shrink it, but Disk Utility says that I can't resize, because of the snapshot tidemark, but I have more than 100GB free space, and the tidemark takes up my whole disk space. I have tried deleting the snapshot, but it says "Resource busy"

I have tried `sudo tmutil deletelocalsnapshots 2023-01-02-210815`, but the output is `Failed to delete local snapshot '2023-01-02-210815'`

Comment: Have you tried `deletelocalsnapshots` without specifying a file, or even `thinlocalsnapshots` ? [Been a long time since I had to fight TM, so I'm a bit out of date]

Comment: Not an answer, but are you leaving enough space for windows to do a system update?

Comment: When I try without specifying a file, it says: `Usage: tmutil deletelocalsnapshots [<mount_point> | <snapshot_date>]`